# My implementation of template_preprocess_block() isn't working

Tags: blocks, theming

My block has `id=block-block-10`, now i want to add a more link after the title.
This is my code in my theme's template.php.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if($variables['block_id'] == 10){
    $variables['block']->subject='<h2>test></h2><span>more</span>';
  }
}
```

There is no more text on the block's title. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the block_id ? `10` or `block-block-10` ?

Comment: block-block-10 this is the block html id label.

Comment: Wrong   `<h2>test>` markup?  If it's not that.. you can try dsm($variables) with devel and see for yourself what's wrong. (If it's not executing the hook or it's because the if condition produces false)

Comment: i'm asking because of your `$variables['block_id'] == 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$variables['block_id']` variable is based on the number of blocks in a region (see [`template_preprocess_block()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_block/6). If you want this for a specific block, despite what region it is in, you should be checking `$variables['block']->delta == 10` instead.